# Insert and ignore duplications

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a list of rows that I want to insert in one batch (add X rows, single call to `SaveChanges`). Unfortunately, from time to time, some of the items in the list already exist. Since the insertion process is taking place in a transaction (all or nothing), nothing gets added.

Code to show the idea:

```
using (var context = new CacheDbContext())
{
    context.Counter.Add(new Counter
    {
        Id = "test-3",
        CounterType = "test",
        Expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        Value = 0
    });
    context.Counter.Add(new Counter
    {
        Id = "test-2",
        CounterType = "test",
        Expiry = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
        Value = 0
    });

    await context.SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

My goal is to do an insertion and if the one or more items are already exists - ignore.

The naive solution is to check if the ID is exists, before insert it. This will work, but it has poor performance. I want to execute multiple inserts, with one call.

I know that it possible using SQL like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name(c1)
VALUES(c1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c1 = VALUES(c1) + 1;
```

if my EF will translate my SQL INSERT statement for something like this, it will be good for me.

Is this possible?

Any other solution will be welcome.

Comment: You should fix your code to *avoid* duplicates in the first place instead of trying to force the INSERT. What you posted isn't valid SQL either, it's a vendor specific syntax that's best described as a hack. If that `c1` is a key, it's an ugly hack that **guarantees duplicate conflicts** and won't scale beyond a few concurrent users. And has poor performance. Why are there any duplicates to begin with?

Comment: If you want to store the latest counter value what you need is an upsert, not ad-or-ignore anyway. That's performed by MERGE in SQL. You don't need an ORM for this operation either as there are no objects/entities involved, just data modification operations. You could use a microORM like Dapper if you wanted to make writing the MERGE statement easier

Comment: Check if key already exist and skip saving, or manage that column in table like unique.
[Unique](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: Checking if exists is inefficiency. Unique wont help (exception will be thrown anyway)..